# Wordpress woocommerce remove cart

Tags: php, css, wordpress, cart

Can someone show me how to remove the woo commerce cart on the theme?

I've tried to remove it from the code but can't find the code for removing cart.

Answer (score 1):

This must be done in two parts:

1. Hide the cart icon
2. Disable Cart functionality

**1. To hide the cart icon**

With Storefront Powerpack, you can remove the cart from header: https://cld.wthms.co/mX0uMs

The end result would be: https://cld.wthms.co/C2kv83

It also comes with a wide range of customization options: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/storefront-powerpack/

If you only want to disable cart icon via CSS, you use the following CSS snippet:

```
/* Hide header - cart */

.site-header-cart {
    display: none;
}
```

Please navigate to **Dashboard > Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS**, add the above snippet and then click on Publish button to save changes.

Note that this will only remove the cart icon, but not the page, or the process itself.

**2. Disable Cart functionality**

Once that’s done, we can either disable cart via custom coding: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/skip-cart-page-go-straight-to-checkout-page-woocommerce/

Or you can disable the cart function by making use of any third party extension that will help you redirect your customers directly to the checkout page. You can find plugins by searching for WooCommerce Add to Cart Redirect in your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

try this . i wish may be its helps you

Comment: let me check again my friend :(

Comment: the theme I'm using is wootique from woothemes

Comment: @Isak Lyberth , sorry My friend i am failed to give solve wootique theme :(

Answer (score 0):

Install the 'code snippets' plugin, then create the following 2 snippets

1. Add the following to redirect to checkout

https://www.codepile.net/pile/Gv2gK8wr

2. Add the following to remove cart text on buttons

https://www.codepile.net/pile/rl54NXwv

Also in Woocommerce>Settings disbale 'add to cart behaviour' options.